# How to set cookie in php?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have use this code as set the cookie for a begginer level. It's basic and not much complex code. Easily understandable by begginer.

````
if(!empty($_POST["remember"])) {
    setcookie ("username",$_POST["username"],time()+ 3600);
    setcookie ("password",$_POST["password"],time()+ 3600);
    echo "Cookies Set Successfuly";
} else {
    setcookie("username","");
    setcookie("password","");
    echo "Cookies Not Set";
}
```
````

Comment: why are u setting a cookie after you have set a session ?? you can access your details from session variable too ??

Comment: _Never_ store passwords in cookies! _Specially_ not in plain text! If you're going to store passwords, you should hash them first using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and store them on the server.

Comment: @Hammad-ahmed-khan yes i am able to access data from session variable, but i am trying is it possible even to set cookie while setting session at the same time when a user visit website.

Comment: @Magnus-Eriksson I am trying on my local server only and it's just for practice as a beginner level, just started learning php. I might dont know everything but from small task only i"ll be able to learn it,

Comment: What you learn with this is just something you should never do. Learn to do things correct and secure from the start and you won't need to unlearn "bad behavior" later on (which is hard and not an uncommon cause of bugs/security issues.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your cookie before the header() function, 
so:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
    {
        $email="dummy@gmail.com";
        $password="dummy123";
    
        if($_REQUEST['email']==$email && $_REQUEST['password']==$password)
        {
            $_SESSION['email']=$email;
            setcookie("email",$email, time()+3600);
            setcookie("password",$password, time()+3600);
            header("location:index.php");
        }
        else {
            $err="Authentication Failed, Try Again!";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

but is not a good idea to save a clear password in cookie :) pay attention

Comment: Totally I understand that it's bad practice to save plain password, i know i have to use md5 encryption and password hash to make secure the password. thank you.